# Crontab and sSMTP

Tags: command-line, email, cron

My server is Ubuntu 12.04.3
Cron jobs are working fine. 
I can send emails through command line, either using `mail`, `ssmtp` or `sendmail`.
I have set the correct email address on top of the `crontab -e`

```
MAILTO=myemail@gmail.com

* * * * *  echo blaaah
```

But what I get in mail.log is

```
sSMTP[4267]: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

Which is strange as I am able to send email through command line. Any ideas?

Comment: `cron` does run as root, right? You can try adding root to the `mail` group, but it _shouldn't_ be required. `usermod -a -G mail root`

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem.  The answer for me was actually quite simple.

The user/environment under which cron executes could not find the ssmtp binary. Simply by adding the full path to it achieved success.

```
# m     h       dom     mon     dow     command
0       9       *       *       *       /usr/sbin/ssmtp a@hotmail.com < /home/a/a-msg.txt
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution. But it is only a workaround. I preferred a solution that applied to the whole crontab

Comment: Been looking all over for this solution.

Comment: Hmm this didn't do anything for me. I assume the `/usr/sbin/ssmtp a@hotmail.com < xyz` xyz refers to the stdout of your command. I get a 550 error this way. Am I missing some steps?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps:
http://community.webfaction.com/questions/11800/how-do-i-set-the-sender-address-for-mail-sent-from-my-cron-jobs

Else more debug output or the exact circumstances would help. "crontab -e" edits the crontab of the current user. Are you sure this user is configured for sending mails?

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp